# How to find patterns between sets of strings in R?

Tags: r, string

I'm trying to find patterns in a set of strings as the following example:

```
"2100780D001378FF01E1000000040000--------01A456000000------------"    
"3100782D001378FF03E1008100040000--------01A445800000------------"
```

If I use the standard get_pattern from the bpa library, since it looks individually to every string I will get

```
"9999999A999999AA99A9999999999999--------99A999999999------------"
```

But my idea would be to find something like:

```
"X10078XD001378FF0XE100XX00040000--------01A4XXX00000------------"
```

The main objective is to find the set of strings with the most similar "pattern"

My first idea was to calculating the hamming distance between them and then analyzing the groups resulting from this distance but it gets tedious. Is there any "automatic" approach?

Any idea of how I can accomplish this mission?

Comment: This looks a lot like what BLAST would do - max matching of sequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your sample data, the code below is working.. no idea how it scales to production...

```
library( data.table )
#sample data
data <- data.table( name = c("2100780D001378FF01E1000000040000--------01A456000000------------",
"3100782D001378FF03E1008100040000--------01A445800000------------"))

#                                                                name
# 1: 2100780D001378FF01E1000000040000--------01A456000000------------
# 2: 3100782D001378FF03E1008100040000--------01A445800000------------


#use data.table::tstrsplit() to split the string to individual characters
l <- lapply( data.table::tstrsplit( data$name, ""), function(x) {
  #if the same character appears in all strings on the same position,return the character, else return 'X'
 if ( length( unique( x ) ) == 1 ) as.character(x[1]) else "X"
})
#paste it all together
paste0(l, collapse = "")

# [1] "X10078XD001378FF0XE100XX00040000--------01A4XXX00000------------"
```

**small explanation**

`data.table::tstrsplit( data$name, "")` returns the following list

```
[[1]]
[1] "2" "3"

[[2]]
[1] "1" "1"

[[3]]
[1] "0" "0"

etc...
```

Using `lapply()`, you can loop over this list, determining the length of the vector with unique elements. Ith this length == 1, then the same character exists in all strings on this position, so return the character.
If the length > 1, then multiple characters apprear on this possition in different strings, and return "X".

## Update

if you are after the hamming distances, use the `stringdist`-package

```
library(stringdist)
m <- stringdist::stringdistmatrix(a = data$name, b = data$name, ,method="hamming" )

#       [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    8
# [2,]    8    0

#to get to the minimum value for each row, exclude the diagonal first (by making it NA)
#  and the find the position with the minimum value
diag(m) <- NA
apply( m, 1, which.min )
# [1] 2 1
```

Comment: Thank you! it is a great start, I will try to find a way to use it in different groups

Comment: I updated with some basics about stringdistance.. might help...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution, where a custom function `findPat` is defined and `Reduce` is applied to find common pattern among a set of strings, i.e.,

```
findPat <- function(s1,s2){
  r1 <- utf8ToInt(s1)
  r2 <- utf8ToInt(s2)
  r1[bitwXor(r1,r2)!=0]<- utf8ToInt("X")
  pat <- intToUtf8(r1)
}

pat <- Reduce(findPat,list(s1,s2,s3))
```

such that

```
> pat
[1] "X10078XDX0X378FF0XE100XX00040000--------01AXXXXX0000------------"
```

**DATA**

```
s1 <- "2100780D001378FF01E1000000040000--------01A456000000------------"
s2 <- "3100782D001378FF03E1008100040000--------01A445800000------------"
s3 <- "4100781D109378FF03E1008100040000--------01A784580000------------"
```